# Best way to clean powder coat overspray

Tags: frames, bmx, paint

I have a BMX frame that has overspray from a powder coating job on one of the v-brake posts, impeding the rotation of the arm back to the original position.

Assuming the idea would be to gently sand this away, but unsure of the exact details. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the masking was not good enough.  If someone professionally did the masking, perhaps ask them to fix it under warranty?

Comment: @Criggie been a while though. Was done in the Spring and we're finally getting to installing parts delivered this week (ordered in December 2020). I did reach out to see what they suggest we do, but I have a bad habit of simply not returning to shops where I don't get satisfactory service.

Answer (score 2):

I would use 400 grit emery cloth. Tear it into strips about the width of the post. With an end in each hand work your way around the post. I would avoid attempting to remove the post. If the powder coating got on to the posts it may chip off the frame if you try to remove them.

Comment: In your opinion, that would be the lowest? Just in case, that my local stores carry different/higher grits.

Comment: Something coarser or finer would work.  The 400 grit is coarse enough to remove the overspray but fine enough  to leave an acceptable finish for the brake arms to pivot on.